# How can I get rid of the scarecrow?

Tags: sir-you-are-being-hunted

The scarecrows appears to be stationary and unable to harm me directly when it notices me, but they seem to call nearby hunters to my location when they notice me. They seem to be quite impervious to damage, and when I try to run away they seem to stalk me by teleporting to my location. How can I shake them off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scarecrow teleports behind you whenever it leaves your field of view. It can't move as long as you look into its direction, but just a split-second is enough for it to teleport. When active, the scarecrow will attract nearby hunters to its location.

There are two ways to get rid of it.

1. kill it. It takes quite a lot of axe-hits, but it will go down after a while. Because it neither moves nor attacks back, using a firearm is a waste of ammo.
2. Run away. Face it and run backwards until its eyes stop to glow. When its eyes stop glowing it is safe to look away.

The first option gives you loot, but that loot rarely has much value. It forces you to stay near the scarecrow for a while, which means that any nearby hunters have more time to close in on you. This can bring you into a quite precarious situation.

The second option has the advantage that you get away from the location to which it called the nearby hunters. When they arrive, you will already have quite a distance from that location. But unfortunately you don't see where you are running, so there is a risk to run blindly into the hunters which are attracted. This option should be chosen when you know (or at least expect) that one direction is relatively save.

Bottom line: When you spot a scarecrow, keep your distance.